# how to do asset management with sprite kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am working on a game project. It includes multiple screens (`mainScreen`, `settingsScreen`, `levelSelectionScreen`, etc). I grouped my icons/images/sounds according to screens such as `main.xcassets`, `settings.xcassets`, `mainsounds`, `settingssounds`, etc. I also have a background directory separately.

I am now looking for something for loading only the necessary resources and disposing of old ones between screen transitions.
When opening the settings screen for example, I want to load only `settingScreen`'s images/sounds and when returning back to `mainScreen` unload the prior screen's resources and load `mainScreen`'s resources. I also want to dispose of the old background image and load the new one when a user changes the background image.

I create my sprites as follows:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myImage")
```

Comment: Use the scene builder then.  The SKS is only going to load the files you need.  As far as memory goes, if no variable is holding onto the reference for whatever image you are using, it will get released from memory.

Comment: I don't use scene editor, I layout everything manually. Is it still valid? thank you.

Comment: You should get used to the scene builder,  million times easier, but yes